# When does the SQL execute in Django ORM

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models, orm

To begin with, I will give an example:

```
# Student is a model class, and it has attributes: name, age, gender and so on.
temp_students = Student.objects.filter(age=18)
students = temp_students.filter(gender='girl')
```

If I debug this code, I can get an SQL which may be `"SELECT * FROM student WHERE age = 18"`(called SQL-A). Then, when I reach the second line, I may get another SQL which is `"SELECT * FROM student WHERE gender = 'girl' IN (SELECT * FROM student WHERE age = 18)"`(called SQL-B).

So, my QUESTION is when does the SQL-A and SQL-B execute? DOES it connect to database twice, and get two result sets? In this case, is there any unnecessary spending for the database? If not so, why can I get the SQL looks like in DEBUG MODE?

It will be great if there is any related Django ORM doc or article at the end of your answer.

THANKS!

Comment: I think you should give this a try https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: Thank you so much, i did not know this tool before. It is awesome, i stared it.

Comment: You can upvote my comment here too :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django querysets are "lazy" - which means they only perform database operation once they are evaluated.

For example here:

```
queryset1 = Student.objects.filter(...)
queryset2 = queryset1.filter(...)

for i in queryset2:
    print(i)
```

In the example above the queryset is only evaluated when it reaches the for-loop, and that's when it's actually accessing the database. It will use one SQL query, that is constructed based on the prior filter statements.

More info in Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy